# Does Unity validate if updates are neccessary on UI-elements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I update UI-Components (espcially Text) regularly in my game. My code looks like this:

```
private void ShowScore(string newScore) {
   var scoreText=Find("Score").GetComponent<Text>();
   if (scoreText.text!=newScore) scoreText.text=newScore;
}
```

My idea behind this is to only update the textbox when the value has really changed and so preventing unneccessary updates that might cause performance issues and/or bad UI experience like "flickering" and so on.

Now my question is: Is that even necessary or does Unity itself already the same validation internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the source code of Unity's UI system is open-source, you can actually look this up. Regarding your question, the specific code is here: https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/31cbc456efd5ed74cba398ec1a101a31f66716db/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Text.cs#lines-212

The relevant part of the setter is

```
else if (m_Text != value)
{
    m_Text = value;
    SetVerticesDirty();
    SetLayoutDirty();
}
```

which, as you suspected, makes sure that the element will only be marked as "dirty" (requiring a visual update) if the new text is different from the one it had before